# Woocommerce get items in the orders before it is process on checkout

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am implementing syncing feature between WordPress and my other site. I want to sync orders to my other site before it is processed during checkout. I needed an items to be sync too, but I don't know what hook to used for this approach.

I tried using `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` the order is already processed and save on the database. I want a hook that will only provide me some information about the order like booking, items and order data before it is being saved on the database. I needed this because if there is some errors during the sync I can cancel the order and it won't be save on the WordPress database.

I tried `woocommerce_checkout_process` hook. The problem is I can't get the items using this code.

```
function syncOrderAsEstimates($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->getItems(); // returns empty
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'syncOrderAsEstimates', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Yves Try using this action hook(/includes/class-wc-checkout.php) :

```
/**
 * Action hook to adjust order before save.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks man but it didn't include the order items. I wanted the items to be able to sync too. It only gives me the information about the shipping and billing info.

Comment: you may get the items from cart:
if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {

 $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

}

Comment: Ohh sorry man but the $order returns empty only the $data has value;

Comment: Edited that as well, happy to help

Comment: May be I will just used woocommerce_checkout_order_processed or woocommerce_checkout_process. and if anything happens on the syncing I will just cancel the order. thanks man..

Comment: have you tried on this way, I am getting order data in their add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'has_order',10, 2 );
function has_order( $order, $data ) {
 var_dump( $order); 
 //your statement
}

Comment: Yes, All the value inside the array were all empty

Comment: hmm, quite surprising.. I am able to get the all the orders details , you may have missed something